# How does one search for a trading good one doesn't have?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

For the Terrain story-line, in one mission the player has to deliver **Teladianium** to a Military Outpost.  The only problem is that I'm not sure where to find Teladianium.  The only trading post that has it is in **Teladi** space and they hate me from the last mission.

Where can I score some Teladianium in or near the Terrain Sectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in your in-game encyclopedia, under 'advanced' in the personal menu (the top button on the left).

Teladianium should be under "Bio". From there you will get a description, pricing information, and locations of where it is made, sold, and purchased.

The last three will only list places that you have found in your exploration.

[More information here](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=257903).

---

If that fails, there should be Teladianium in the sector **Ceo's Buckzold**.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a good [online resource](http://eng.x3tc.ru) that allows you to search for wares and list them by station/sector, and there is a good universe map there to see which sectors are nearby.